# Avoid already exists validation on update and do update in Spring MVC

Tags: java, spring-mvc

I am creating a simple CRUD using Spring MVC. I am using same form for insert and edit.  I have created a validation for name field, to check whether the value already exists.  How can I avoid this on edit validation and how can I do an update?

Here is the code

ItemController.java

```
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String processForm(  @Validated  ItemForm itemForm, BindingResult result,
        Map model) {                                
    if (result.hasErrors()) {           
        model.put("typeList", dao.getItemTypes());
        return "itemmaster";
    }
    dao.insertItems(itemForm);      
    return "redirect:dashboard";
}
```

and this the jsp page

```
<form:form action="itemmaster.html"  commandName="itemForm">
<table width="100%" border="0">
    <tr>
        <td width="7%">Name:</td>
        <c:choose>
<c:when test="${not empty name}">
   <td width="11%"><form:input path="nameUpdate" /></td><td width="82%"><form:errors cssStyle="color:red" path="nameUpdate"/></td>
</c:when>
<c:otherwise>
    <td width="11%"><form:input path="name" /></td><td width="82%"><form:errors cssStyle="color:red" path="name"/></td>
</c:otherwise>
</c:choose>                     
    </tr>       
        <td>Description:</td><td><form:textarea path="description" /></td><td width="13%"><form:errors path="description" cssStyle="color:red"/></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td></td><td><input type="submit" value="Submit" /></td>
    </tr>
</table>
</form:form>
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IMHO you should not do duplicate test in the validator. You should separe *formal* validation (deal with empty fields and acceptable formatting) from *logic* validation. The first part depends only on input values, the latter may depend on external context such as database. Only the first part should be done in automatic validation.

My advice is :

- use different controller methods for update and insert
- remove the duplicate test from the validator
- in insert method add the duplicate test

  ```
  public String processForm(  @Validated  ItemForm itemForm, BindingResult result,
          Map model) {
      if (hasDuplicatedName(itemForm) {
          result.reject(DUPLICATE, "Name is already in use");
      }
      if (result.hasErrors()) {           
          model.put("typeList", dao.getItemTypes());
          return "itemmaster";
      }
      ...
  ```

You could also use the transaction demarcation as a rule : if you need to read database to to a test, it should not be done in controller but at service level. I often pass the binding result to service layer (as an `Error`) to do *logic tests* at this level, still being able to display errors later in the view

Comment: Sorry for my late comment.  I am a beginner in Spring MVC. I guess I have posted this question at the incorrect time.  I have problem in using same form submit method (processForm) for both insert and update and unable to use different submit button methods for the same form.  Should I start a separate thread? or update in this same thread?

Comment: moved the duplicate test from validator to controller and this answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/26463149/375941 helped me a lot :)  My problem is now solved.  Thanks :)